# Dynamic variable creation from Excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different template that I want pandas to read both, my issue is that part of my code checks a column and the values within to a JSON file that contains a list of standard values. the column name of interest is "Industry" for template 1 and "Industry EU" for template 2. They have different standard values in the JSON file

```
with open('valid.json', 'r') as validvals:
    valid = json.load(validvals)

#checking for industry, Industry EU, AccountType and System_Type__c Standard values
df1= df[['industry','System_Type__c','AccountType', 'Industry EU','country','state']]
mask = df1.apply(lambda c: c.isin(valid[c.name]))
df1.mask(mask|df1.eq(' ')).stack()
for err_i, (r, v) in enumerate(df1.mask(mask|df1.eq(' ')).stack().iteritems()):
    errors[filename][err_i] = {"row": r[0],
                               "column": r[1],
                               "message": v + " is invalid check column " + r[1] + ' and replace with a standard value'}
```

above is the code for checking the value in the column vs the value in the JSON titled valid. The issue I am having with this since there are now two templates one template contains "Industry" and one contains "Industry EU" so when the above code runs it will say "column industry not found".

How do I make python read the column names first before making them fixed so the code will adapt to the missing column name?

Note: excel file name is not significant since this is being used with another interface that the data is imported in with different file names. I just need the code to recognize what variables are included in the file since it changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could swap around what you're checking - if you set up your valid values as a list, then cycle over the contents of the json keys, testing that each key exists in your list.

```
valid_list=['industry','System_Type__c','AccountType', 'Industry EU','country','state']
for k in valid.keys():
    if k not in valid_list:
        print ( f"The value {k} isn't recognised as a valid value." )
```

That way, the test is performed based on what is loaded from the file, rather than from your merged collection, which will always fail since it contains a specification (all the columns) that will never exist in practice.